# ls to list directories sorted by date in timestamp AND by date in filename appendix results in little satisfaction

Tags: linux, ls

For listing of directories I always use commands like

```
ls -la --time-style=long-iso <directoryname>
```

And all is at best.

Yet on some cases I append a date-time suffix to the filename. This is especially the case when I make backup copies of bash history files. A line of ls output may look as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234567  2023-10-23 20:39  /root/.bash_history.WE_2023-10-23_23-13-10_CEST
```

When I am developing a bash script, for example, the timestamp says, the state of 20:39 is in the $HISTFILE, and the backup was  written with my test-run of my  script at 23:13:10.

This is ok.

But after having made three test-runs, the output of ls is as follows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234567  2023-10-23 20:39  /root/.bash_history.WE_2023-10-23_23-13-10_CEST

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234567  2023-10-23 20:39  /root/.bash_history.WE_2023-10-23_23-23-10_CEST

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234567  2023-10-23 20:39  /root/.bash_history.WE_2023-10-23_23-33-10_CEST
```

The problem I have since tens of years is the order of date-time sorting ls makes.

I want to have the newest date-time first in the list.

ls with the option -t makes just so for sorting by timestamp.

But if there is a cluster of many files with the same timestamp, this cluster is listed by ls in the wrong order: oldest filename-date first.

If ls would beside primal sorting key timestamp also observe the filecreation date-time, ls would sort correctly. But ls does not.

Today again I have tried to find a solution, without succsess.

In less the option -v does not conduce tward succeds.

And feeding the output of ls through the utility sort, also does not give the correct results.

Yes, if I take only into account the cluster of equal timestamps,
by that means I can reverse the order. but as sideeffects other things get out of order. E.G. the file "/root/.bash_history" without an appedix to the filename is written by ls as the top line, the first line. With such measures I tried, this filename is then somewhere in the middle of the list.

I have googled in Internet and have found very many articles about ls sorting by date, but nothing to my problem.

Has anyone else suffered from this problem, and please is there a known solution

Regards.

Comment: Unix filesystems do not generally store creation time, so `ls` doesn't support it. Unix does store the inode-change time, called ctime, and if you created the file e.g. with `cp` and didn't do anything else to it since creating it, ctime will normally be the same as creation time and you can sort on it with `-t -c` (descending) or `-t -c -r` (ascending). OTOH if you have the creation time bigendian in the filename, why don't you just sort by _filename_ descending i.e. `ls -r` (no `-t`) (or even `ls | tac`)?

Comment: "But if there is a cluster of many files with the same timestamp" – Timestamps may be stored with resolution that greatly exceeds what you see with `--time-style=long-iso`. AFAIK `ls -t` sorts using actual timestamps, not formatted timestamps. Please use `--time-style=full-iso` and confirm that there really is "a cluster of many files with the same timestamp". *Maybe* the problem is not exactly what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but "--time-style=long-iso" is of no help. I think about utility sort could be the basics, because it allows to use different parts of line in different ways for sorting, e.g. key -k6,7 to sort by timestamp and additionally -k8.24,8.42 to sort by a part of filename. Yet it would be a hard job to receive the wanted results. The difficulties begin with the fact, that when utility sort does sort by timestamp the resultant order is different from that of ls. And even the filenames "abc" (without appendix) and "abc_x" are handled differently in respect of collation. And

Comment: collation. And ls and sort react differently on locales. Many years ago I had a tricky solution for this top line of ls, now forgotten. Yet for the needed case a regex must be applied that sort only touch the resp. part of filenam if regex matches. I wonder that in all the yeats Linux does not have a uniform good solution. Please, does anyone know a solution. Regards.

Comment: `--time-style=long-iso` is something *you* used. I asked you to use `--time-style=full-iso`, but only to confirm that there really is "a cluster of many files with the same timestamp". I did not say it will help. *Maybe* all the timestamps are different but you just don't see it with `--time-style=long-iso`.